# Seeking Help Optimizing a small jQuery Plugin

Tags: jquery, optimization, jquery-plugins

I wrote the following plugin - and it runs perfectly. It does EXACTLY What I want it to do in all situations - but it is kind of slow. I thought I might defer to a wiser community to see if anyone saw a way I might dramatically increase its performance.

Basically put, it takes a structured `ul` and makes the stereotypical dropdown/drawers functionality. I'm also posting a snippet of the HTML it expects.

#### Warning - I am including a very large amount of HTML because I want to demonstrate how many items it is using - which may tell you why it is slow.

I am fairly sure the slowdown is merely because of the ridiculous quantity of items I am telling it to process. But because I want it to fold all other menus when any is clicked, I have to attach them all - right?

I'll repeat - the behavior you see here is EXACTLY right. I'm also including a jsFiddle, so you can see it in action.

### [jsFiddle Link (Working)](http://jsfiddle.net/ciel/tTeuR/)

## jQuery Wiring (document load)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".dropdown > a").addClass("root");

    var $sidebar_dropdown = $('li[data-role="sidebar-dropdown"]');
    var $submenu_dropdown = $('li[data-role="sidebar-sub-dropdown"]');
    var $remote_menus = $('a.remote');

    $sidebar_dropdown.drawer({
        openClass: 'sidebar-dropdown-open'
    });
    $submenu_dropdown.drawer({
        openClass: 'sidebar-sub-dropdown-open'
    });

});
```

## Actual Plugin (Javascript)

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.drawer = function (options) {
        // Create some defaults, extending them with any options that were provided
        var settings = $.extend({
            openClass: 'open',
            openClassName: function () { return '.' + this.openClass; }
        }, options);

        var open = function (e) {
            // mark this menu as open
            $(e).addClass(settings.openClass);

            // retrieve the appropriate menu item
            var $menu = $(e).children(".dropdown-menu, .sidebar-dropdown-menu");

            // slide down the one clicked on.
            $menu.slideDown(100);
            $menu.addClass('active');
        };

        var close = function (e) {
            $(e).removeClass(settings.openClass);
            // retrieve the appropriate menu item
            var $menu = $(e).children(".dropdown-menu, .sidebar-dropdown-menu");
            // slide down the one clicked on.
            $menu.slideUp('fast');
            $menu.removeClass('active');
        };

        return this.each(function () {
            $(this).on('click', function (e) {
                // transform the selector into a 'className'
                var $className = $('.' + settings.openClass);
                var $node = $(this); // the current node
                var $target = $(e.target); // the actual DOM target
                // examine all existing dropdown menus that are
                // currently open, and close them - excluding the
                // current one.
                $className.not($(this)).each(function () {
                    close($(this));
                });

                if ($target.hasClass("root") && $node.hasClass(settings.openClass)) {
                    close($(this));
                }
                else {
                    // open the selected dropdown menu
                    open($(this));
                }

                // prevent default event propogation
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
            }).on("mouseleave", function () {
                $(this).children(".dropdown-menu").hide().delay(300);
            });

        })
    };

})(jQuery);
```

## HTML

```
<div class="page-sidebar">
<ul>
    <li class="dropdown" data-role="sidebar-dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu light sidebar-dropdown-menu">
            <li><a class="remote" href="#">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a class="remote" href="#">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a class="remote" href="#">Test Menu Item</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown" data-role="sidebar-dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu light sidebar-dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class=" dropdown" data-role="sidebar-dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu light sidebar-dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class=" dropdown" data-role="sidebar-dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu light sidebar-dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class=" dropdown" data-role="sidebar-dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu light sidebar-dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class=" dropdown" data-role="sidebar-dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu light sidebar-dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class=" dropdown" data-role="sidebar-dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu light sidebar-dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li class=" dropdown" data-role="sidebar-dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu light sidebar-dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class=" dropdown" data-role="sidebar-dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu light sidebar-dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class=" dropdown" data-role="sidebar-dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu light sidebar-dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class=" dropdown" data-role="sidebar-dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu light sidebar-dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class=" dropdown" data-role="sidebar-dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu light sidebar-dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class=" dropdown" data-role="sidebar-dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu light sidebar-dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class=" dropdown" data-role="sidebar-dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu light sidebar-dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class=" dropdown" data-role="sidebar-dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu light sidebar-dropdown-menu">
            <li class="dropdown" data-role="sidebar-sub-dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu light sidebar-dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#" class="remote">
                            Test Menu Item,
                            <br />
                            <small>Test Menu Item Small</small>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="remote">
                            Test Menu Item,
                            <br />
                            <small>Test Menu Item Small</small>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown" data-role="sidebar-sub-dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu light sidebar-dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown" data-role="sidebar-sub-dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu light sidebar-dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown" data-role="sidebar-sub-dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu light sidebar-dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown" data-role="sidebar-sub-dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu light sidebar-dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#" class="remote">Test Menu Item</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>​
```

## CSS

```
.page-sidebar {
    display: block;
    width: 213px;
    float: left;
    min-height: 100% !important;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #EBEBEB;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 7px;
}
.page-sidebar ul.sub-menu.light {
    background-color: #F9F9F9 !important;
}
.page-sidebar ul.sub-menu {
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
.page-sidebar .sidebar-dropdown-menu {
    display: none;
}
.page-sidebar ul {
    margin-left: 0;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #EBEBEB;
}
.page-sidebar > ul > li > a {
    font-size: 1.1em;
}
.page-sidebar > ul > li.dropdown {
    position: relative;
}
.page-sidebar li {
    display: list-item;
    line-height: 20px;
    position: relative;
}
.dropdown, .dropdown > a {
    font-weight: 600 !important;
}
ul li, ol li {
    display: list-item;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
}
.dropdown, .dropdown > a {
    font-weight: 600 !important;
}
.page-sidebar a {
    font-family: 'Almendra', 'Segoe UI', 'Open Sans', Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 11pt;
    letter-spacing: 0.01em;
    line-height: 14pt;
    color: black;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px 20px 5px 10px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size: 14px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
a, .link {
    font-family: 'Almendra', 'Segoe UI', 'Open Sans', Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 11pt;
    color: #2E92CF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.page-sidebar > ul > li.dropdown::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 6px;
    left: 100%;
    margin-left: -20px;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    background: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 -1586px;
    z-index: 200;
}
```

​

Comment: The fiddle seems pretty fast. Is it slower in production?

Comment: Yeah, it is. Perhaps my machine is just troublesome. This is my very first jQuery plugin, so I figured I was just doing a lot wrong and would ask the smarter community (you guys). Maybe I actually did it right ...

Comment: I mean, it looks good from what I can see. Obviously everyone has their own design style so perhaps it could be structured differently. But as far as speed goes, I don't see anything egregious. Usually what slows down animation is having a lot of intervals or timeouts running at the same time, or manipulating the dom one piece at a time instead of all at once. This doesn't seem to exhibit either of those traits.

Comment: I kind of figured the whole thing would be blasted apart for bad design. Never in my wildest dreams did I conceive it would work right for someone else, Lol.

Comment: maybe you are having browser specific problem? Or perhaps your browser memory peaked out. FF gives me fits sometimes after many hours and Firebug running  WOrked pretty well for me in 2 browsers

Comment: one minor suggestion... `$(e)` used but you pass `$(this)` to function argument, so no need to wrap `e` in `$()` again

Comment: In the `click` handler there are a couple of `$(this)` that can be replaced with `$node`. If you use a Javascript IDE, it may have an option to highlight repeated uses of expressions like that (I use PhpStorm).

Comment: That's odd. Changing the `$(this)` to `$node` changes the behavior entirely.

Answer (score 0):

I try to understand the situation.
I was browsing your plugin and it looks good.
Exactly that is what is slow?
The accordion effect is slow?